# Ubuntu 13.04 and Steam

Tags: 12.04, 13.04, games, steam

I am having a major issue with steam working on Ubuntu. I previously had steam working on Ubuntu 12.04LTS but after upgrading to Ubuntu 13.04 I have had issues. There are two issues, first sometimes that Steam client just shuts down and is no responsive. The second and most troubling issue is the inability to use the steam store. I will click on the store tab a search for any game then after clicking on the game that I want steam kind of freezes. I mean freezes because the icon in the upper right corner next to the "big picture" button shows that Steam is working. But after leaving this open for an hour or so there was no change.

I have deleted and re-downloaded steam many times, check inter net connection, ect I am at a loss.

If anyone could please help it would be much appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

When you uninstalled, did you remove your .steam folder in your home directory?

Note that before you do that, you should backup the game files so you don't have to download all your games again.

If you didn't then it is likely that some setting has corrupted in your home folder that didn't get cleared when you uninstalled it.

Just to add that I upgraded from 12.10 to 13.04 without issues and Steam works perfectly so it should work once you clear the old files.

Comment: No that did not help/work good idea though. Some more additional information, when the store is 'stuck' i can not scroll at all. I can however switch back to the library, community and my profile. I deleted the .steam folder then restarted my computer FYI, still does not work.

Comment: Any other ideas?

Comment: You can also run steam from the command line once installed by typing steam into a terminal.  Should work from anywhere.  This will output a bunch of stuff to the console.  Even I get loads of errors even though it works flawlessly for me but you might be able to spot something if you perform the same action that doesn't work a few times while monitoring the output to see if anything pops up repeatedly when you perform that action that looks like it might be the source of the problem.

Comment: Also try reading this issue on the steam Github to see if it looks like your issue.  Pay attention to the latest comments relating to flash 64bit
https://github.com/ValveSoftware/steam-for-linux/issues/2365